# Ошибка 500 в подключении мобильной версии?

Tags: php, mobile

Подключаю отдельную мобильную версию из папки в корне сайта или на поддомене.
Использую этот плагин https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

Но когда я его подключаю в index.php сайт не работает с HTTP ERROR 500

```
<?php
require_once '/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if(!NOMOBILE and ($detect->isMobile() or $detect->isTablet())){
header("Location: ".'http://m.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
Здесь сайт
.....
```

Логи

```
[Mon Jan 20 13:55:56.075512 2020] [:error] [pid 27837] [client 94.25.239.214:47314] PHP Warning:  require_once(/Mobile_Detect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/www-root/data/www/site.ru/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jan 20 13:55:56.075598 2020] [:error] [pid 27837] [client 94.25.239.214:47314] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/Mobile_Detect.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/www-root/data/www.....
```

Comment: В логах что пишет?

Comment: где их смотреть?

Comment: А вообще мне кажется что ошибка из-за этого `NOMOBILE` что это?

Comment: Разные варианты пробовал, без этих строк тоже ошибка. Даже только с этими строками `require_once '/Mobile_Detect.php'; $detect = new Mobile_Detect();` Может из-за версии php? У меня 5.4

Comment: Вообще ошибка должна быть написана в логах, поищите у своего хостера

Comment: Нашел. Что она значит? В вопросе

Comment: Если у вас файл лежит в той же папке что и индекс то измените подключение на `require_once './Mobile_Detect.php';`

Comment: Ещё вопросик. Если зашел в моб версию на ПК, то как перенаправить в корень сайта?

Comment: та же проверка только в обратную сторону и перенаправление на десктоп

Comment: Правильно? `if ($detect->isMobile() or $detect->isTablet()){
  header("Location: ".'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/app/index.php');
} else { header("Location: ".'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/index.php'); } `